# How do you create a message "An Update is Available" for a Joomla extension?

Tags: php, joomla, message

Joomla checks after logging in backend if there are any updates available. If yes, you can see an overview when clicking on 'View Updates'. But I want to show a similar message about updates for an extension developed by me ('there is an update available'). I've tried some things but so far I didn't manage. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe check the code for Akeeba Backup which has the functionality you describe.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I am following for my component. You can use the same in the views->tmpl->default.php file

```
<?php $user = JFactory::getUser();  ?>

<div class="UpdatesPage" style="margin-top: 8px">
<?php 
$xml = JFactory::getXML(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR .'/components/com_mycomponent/manifest.xml');//Path to your existing manifest file. 
$existingversion = (string)$xml->version;

$url = 'http://example.com/downloads/mycomponent.xml';
//$url is path to your xml file which stores the latest version.
$ch = curl_init($url);//Execute curl and get the xml data available in my server

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
// 400 means not found, 200 means found.
curl_close($ch);
if($retcode == 200){
$xml2 = JFactory::getXML($url,true);
  $latestversion = $xml2->update->version;
} else {
  $latestversion = "";
}

?>
<h2>Version Update</h2>
<?php
if ( version_compare($latestversion, $existingversion) > 0) {
    echo "<span style='color:#AFA;text-align:center;'>The version installed is ".$existingversion."</span><br />";
    echo "<span style='color:red;text-align:center;'>The latest version is ".$latestversion."</span><br />";    

} else {
    echo "<span style='color:green;text-align:center;'>You have the Latest version</span>"; 
}
?>
</div>
```

This is the xml file in my server where I update it so that my component users can see when they visit my component updates page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<updates>
    <update>
        <name><![CDATA[My Component]]></name>
        <description><![CDATA[Download Component]]></description>
        <element>pkg_mycomponent</element>
        <type>package</type>
        <client>0</client>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <infourl title="example.com">http://www.example.com</infourl>
        <downloads>
           <downloadurl type="full" format="zip">https://example.com/index.php?option=com_mycomponent</downloadurl>
       </downloads>
        <tags>
            <tag>stable</tag>
        </tags>
        <maintainer><![CDATA[Amit Ray]]></maintainer>
        <maintainerurl>http://www.example.com</maintainerurl>
        <section>Testing</section>
        <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3"/>
    </update>
</updates>
```

Comment: still one problem: my update xml and update file is on a site with https, this seems no problem when I working local. Then the script is working fine. When I try the script on a live site with https, I get an error that the XML file from my updatesite couldn't be read. Joomla on the other hand does show the update correct in the updates list. Could this problem be solvable within the script?

Comment: @Franky In the `$url = 'http://example.com/downloads/mycomponent.xml';` are you using http or https? As you are saying this is https so you need to change this variable to https. So your url should be `$url = 'https://example.com/downloads/mycomponent.xml';`

Comment: Yes, I've in the url https from the start, and in $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); I've switched afterwards also to https. But doesn't make any difference, XML is not loaded. Strange...

Comment: @Franky I am surprised why that's not working as my component is working fine even though I use https.